# CakePHP: image inside link, want to make link point to image location

Tags: php, image, cakephp, hyperlink, html-helper

I have some images inside links that I want to essentially look like this:

```
<a href="/path/to/img.png"><img src="/path/to/img.png" /></a>
```

Clicking on the link should load the image it contains. I'm trying to use CakePHP's HTML helper to do this, as follows:

```
<?php
  echo $html->link(
    $html->image('img.png'),
    'img.png',
    array('escape' => false)
  );
?>
```

When I do this, however, I get the following code:

```
<a href="/pages/img.png"><img src="/path/to/img.png" /></a>
```

**Without using absolute URLs**, can I make the link's `href` attribute point to the image's correct location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
echo $html->image('image.png', array('url' => '/' . IMAGES_URL . 'image.png'));
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know about the `IMAGES_URL` constant. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you can also do this in 1.2

```
echo $html->link(
    $html->image('img.png'),
    'img.png',
    array(),
    null, 
    false
  );
```

or in 1.3

```
echo $html->link(
    $html->image('img.png'),
    'img.png',
    array(),
    array( 'escape' => false ),     
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but by leaving the link URL as `img.png` Cake uses the `Pages` controller to handle it, making the URL `example.com/pages/img.png`. This is why the `IMAGES_URL` constant is needed. My code ended up looking like this:

    echo $html->link(
      $html->image('img.png'),
      '/' . IMAGES_URL . '/img.png',
      array('escape' => false)
    );