# How to display an image inside a link in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CakePHP: image inside link, want to make link point to image location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878301/cakephp-image-inside-link-want-to-make-link-point-to-image-location)

I'm trying to add an image (in $avatar) to a link in cakephp, but it displays as the text

```
echo $this->Html->link( $avatar, '/notifications/ajax_show', array( 
    'class' => 'overlay', 
    'title' => 'text' ) 
));
```

It's not possible to use the url parameter of $this->Html->image because I want to set a class on the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the escape param is not only well documented, there is also an exact duplicate as example available:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link

Comment: I did research for over an hour, and could not find any way to solve this, even though I checked that question! I didn't expect to find an answer in the question though :o. Anyway, thanks!